# Playing mkv files

Tags: opensuse, video

I'm having trouble playing mkv files in Kaffeine, or any other player on openSUSE, which generally doesn't come with this type of codec.

I've already installed a mkv codec that I found in the openSUSE repository. Still, the player can't play this format.

I tried installing VLC with a built-in codec for mkv, but ended up with lots of problems and decided to back out.

What solution could I use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that MKV is not a codec, but only a container.
Imagine it's just a .TAR file, with files for 1 or more tracks of audio, video and subtitles.

You have to figure out what format are the audio and video in the MKV file.

Install the mkvtoolnix suite and use mkvinfo-gui (or mkvinfo for the console version) to figure this out, then install the codecs.

Beside that, I found VLC to be a very good player. It works very well as soon as you have all the needed codecs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need the [packman repository](http://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories#Packman). It contain a lot of extra packages.